# Not able to force user to authenticate captcha along with email & password after 4 failed login attempts

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all I am very new to PHP and currently working on a small login project using PHP MYSQL. Authentication part is fine as far as email & password requirement is concerned. However I would like to use recaptcha after 5 failed attempts, hence using the below code. My problem is irrespective of number of failed attempts I can't force user to verify recaptcha as they can sign-in after 10/20/30 failed attempts with correct email & password without verifying captcha. I am not using IPaddress check neither timestamp its just against an email address I am using to keep track of failed login attempts. May be I am not able to search effectively over internet but please help...!!!

```
  <?php
         session_start(); // Starting Session

        #Database connection
         include('../config/connection.php');


        $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
        if (empty($_POST['email']) OR empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = '<p class="alert alert-danger">One or either field is missing</p>';
        }

           $q = "SELECT login_attempts from users where email = '$email'";
           $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) OR die(mysqli_error());  
           $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

                   if($row['login_attempts']>=5){

                    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
                    $privatekey = "====key====";
                    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."$response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);   
                    $data = json_decode($response);

                    if(!(isset($data->success)) OR $data->success==false) {

                        $error = "Captch verification required as you have failed login more than 5 times !!!";

                    }

        } else {

        // Define $username and $password
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);
        $password = md5(SHA1($_POST['password']));


        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
            $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password ='$password' AND Activation IS NULL";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)or die(mysqli_error());
            $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($r);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
              if( $num_row ==1 )
            {

                $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
                header('Location:Index.php');

            } else {
                $query = "UPDATE users SET login_attempts=login_attempts+1 WHERE email='$email'";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error());

                $error = '<p class="alert alert-danger">Username or Password don\'t match</p>';
                    }
                mysqli_close($dbc); // Closing Connection
            }
        }
        ?>

        <body>

    <div class="container" id="recovery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
          <div class="panel-heading"><h2 class="panel-title"> <strong>Login</strong> </h2></div>
          <div class="panel-body">
          <?php if(isset($error) AND $error !=''){echo $error; }?></p>
            <form action="signin.php" method="post" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                 <a href ="recovery.php" style="float:right">Can't access my account</a>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
               <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcvdBMTAAAAAIYXE3ep-iUx5AWDvH7qmRdh00it"></div>
              </div>

                <button type="submit" name= "submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button><br/><br/>

              <span>Not a member yet&nbsp&nbsp<a href ="register.php">Sign Up</a></span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see a few things that should perhaps be addressed, the largest of which is the possibility of sql injection - use prepared statements in preference to writing the variables into the sql statements. The `$error` vars that you populate don't appear to get used ( no doubt there is more code which you have not shown ), the code above is missing a final closing curly brace and the `if($row['login_attempts'] >= 4){` is not tied to the current date in any way so over time if a user were to login and fail he/she would still hit the maximum of 4 limit.

Comment: I would recommend you to use 'mysqli_escape_string' function. But :
"This function was deprecated in PHP 4.3.0, and it and the entire original MySQL extension was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, use either the actively developed MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions." Consider this

Comment: Thanks Ram & Roman. Please have a look at the complete quote with some changes as per your feedback but it still not forcing the user to validate captcha after 'X' failed attempts.

Comment: Why are saving attempts in database? Is there any need in future if not than save failed attempts in cookies

Comment: Hi Dev, Thanks for the suggestion. As I mentioned I am very new to PHP and trying to learn through what I could understand from info available to. I am aware of achieving this via cookie but not sure how to implement that ....hence using this method.

Comment: Very simple @gautam: create a cookie and update as like your update query +1 value

Comment: And plz also tag my full username in comment. I knw this ia not your answer I just try share a new way of saving thing

Comment: @devpro storing login attempt in cookies is equivalent to removing the captcha at all. What would stop an attacker from clearing or modifying the cookie before attempting another login? @GautamPBehera, the logic of your ifs is the problem. What exactly are you trying to check with `if (isset($_POST['submit'])`? Why are you looking at failed attempts in one branch and check for email/password in another one? Only one of two branches would get executed, you know.

Comment: @Timekiller on if (isset($_POST['submit']), I would like to check if either email or password field is empty, if not I wd like to check if number of failed attempts made by that user is more than 5, if true then the user will need to do the captcha verification before he can log in on 6th or seventh time. What wd you recommend, if I have managed to clarify myself. It is just for learning purpose....

Comment: I'm asking what are you trying to achieve by even checking if `$_POST['submit']` is set, and why is your login code in the `else` branch for that check, i.e. it will only get executed if `$_POST['submit']` is empty? I'd recommend trying to understand what happens when your code is executed. If it's for learning purposes, then don't ask for help, work it out yourself. Use a debugger, or echo something in the line that's supposed to get executed but isn't, or echo variable values and compare them to what you expect.

Comment: It will only work when the form is submitted if user doesn't click submit button php code will not execute. Once $_POST['submit'], it will check if any error checks are true is so it will not take the user to Index page if no error it will display index page. when I say for learning purpose it doesn't mean I will not implement it in my project please help if you can...

Thanks

Comment: Thank you all I am so glad to have it worked out finally !!!